# Node.js saving file from multipart native

Tags: node.js, forms, file, upload, multipart

i have a question: How i could save file from multipart/form-data in native node.js without modules like busboy etc?

I have a simple form:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file1">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

and:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk.toString());
    });
})
```

chunk returned this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCAtgaK18LJANVeUL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="somefile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Some content from txt file... blablabla...
------WebKitFormBoundaryCAtgaK18LJANVeUL--
```

How can i save it as a file from this? What is the best way to create uploading file system from this?

Comment: Why are you needing to avoid modules like `busboy`? Do you really want to implement your own multipart parser?

Comment: IMO the only good reasons for avoiding libs are "they don't do what I need" and "i want to learn how to do it". in both cases I suggest reading the source code of the libs (for example [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) and [node-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty))

Comment: I should also add that using a third-party module and writing your own multipart parser are the only solutions since there is no multipart parser built-in to node.js.